# Pasar el sen, cos, tan a grados con lambda en Python

Tags: python

```py
'*': lambda x: str(float(x[0]) * float(x[1])),
'/': lambda x: str(float(x[0]) / float(x[1])),
'+': lambda x: str(float(x[0]) + float(x[1])),
'-': lambda x: str(float(x[0]) - float(x[1])),
```

Estoy haciendo una calculadora contextual, pero tengo que implementar las funciones trigonométricas, pero en grados no en radianes pero no, no se cómo implementarlo con lambda y que se pudiera validar con paréntesis,  o me pudieran dar un ejemplo de hacerlo de otra manera, les agradecería un montón Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Tu codigo solo hace las operaciones básicas de matemáticas, no saca el coseno ni la tangente ni nada de eso

Comment: Esos lambdas están convirtiendo floats en string?

Comment: Si , mi programa tiene que validar un input como string  y para convertirlo a una operación  y me calcule las operaciones básicas y compuestas y que haga las funciones trigonométricas

Comment: tiene que validarse con paréntesis todo lo que vamos a calcular

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar te recomiendo importar la librería math

```
import math
```

Luego configuras:

```
'sen': lambda x: str(float (math.degrees(math.cos(x[0])))
```

y así con las otras funciones.

Creo que deseas convertir a string los resultados.

Comment: Las funciones cos, sin y tang del modulo math devuelven el resultado en radianes. Puedes convertir radianes a grados con math.degrees.

Comment: Gracias! Ya edité la respuesta. Tu comentario fue muy útil!

Comment: En realidad, es justo a la inversa. Hay que convertir el ángulo de grados a radianes antes de hacer la operación: `math.cos(math.radians(x[0]))`

Comment: Muchas gracias me ayudaste un montón, soy nuevo en programación

Comment: @JeanGotopo Disculpa no me sirve los paréntesis quisiera saber como solucionar este problema al momento que evalúo no funciona bien

Comment: @JeanGotopo Aquí esta mi código muy agradecido con tu ayuda

Comment: @ChemaCortes Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @DanteS. Muchas gracias me ayudo mucho